# Android: client-server, user authentication

Tags: android, authentication, client-server

I have never built any such Android Application which will communicate with the sever. What I want to do is I want to send username and password to the server, match them on server and when the username and password matches next screen should be shown. Next screen should have only one text view saying "Welcome username".

I want you guys to tell me **step by step guide** for -

1. What should I write in the Android App?
2. What should I write on server side?
3. How and where to write server code?
4. Which language should I use for server side?
5. How to save several usernames-passwords on the server?

I don't have real server. I will run the entire code on localhost.

**UPDATE:**

This is what I wrote in my Android app. I don't know how much is correct.

```
public void clicked(View v) {
    System.out.println("button clicked");
    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edituser);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpass);

    Editable user = username.getText();
    Editable pass = password.getText();

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.101:8080//WebApplication1/sendresponse.java");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass.toString()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
        int len = headers.length;
        for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            System.out.println("header : " + headers[i]);
        }

        InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String bufferedStrChunk = null;

        while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
        }
        System.out.println("response : " + stringBuilder.toString());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }



}
```

I don't know which language will be best for server side. Should I use REST on server side?

Comment: Whoever answers this question should get +5000 rep

Comment: @Ken Wolf Are you making fun of me? Can you please answer this question if you know all these?

Comment: maybe if you try step by step (using google) and show your code we could help you in each question.

Comment: @NiteshKhatri not making fun. It is a rather large question though and I believe the answerer should be adequately rewarded :)

Comment: @NiteshKhatri He is just saying it is not common someone is going to answer any question that requires writing a rather substantial project entirely from scratch for another person.

Comment: Should we prepare this app for you??

Comment: `What should I write in the Android App?` just answering the first question will take a few work days.

Comment: @NiteshKhatri You've obviously not familiarized yourself with this site. Check out the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia I understand but at least give me some clues. Tell me something anything.

Comment: @ArnaldoGaspar Thanks mate. I added my android code. Is it ok?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll authenticate using php. First of all,

```
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/login.php");
```

10.0.2.2 reffers localhost from emulator. For real device, you need real server.

You have to create DB & table at localhost using phpmyadmin.(Assuming you are using WAMP/LAMP)

Now, my php file is like this:

```
   <?php 
$link=mysql_connect('localhost','root','password');// give your username & password
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
}  
mysql_select_db("database_name"); 
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Login_Table_name where user_name = '".$_REQUEST['username']."' and password = '".$_REQUEST['password']."'");
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
 echo "success";
}else{
echo "login failed"; 
}
mysql_close($link); 
?>
```

(Assuming you know where to put the php file, for localhost)(www folder for WAMP/LAMP)

Now, coming back to java, leave the steps upto this line as it is. And change code from here to

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
String res=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
if(res.contains("success")){
//login success
}
else{
//loginfailed
}
```

Now you can say how to store usernames and passwords. Yes, just create an another registration form, wrap namevaluepairs and send to another php in which the sql query will change to 'INSERT INTO'.

NB: If you run this on emulator with API-14+, you will get an exception- Network on main thread exception. You have to use AsynvTask. so try in API-10.

**EDIT:**

If you need some values back from server, encode to JSON and send. changes will be as,

**php**

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){// you can use either fetch_assoc or fetch_array
    $result[]=$row;
    }
echo json_encode($result);
}
```

**Java**

```
String res=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
Log.d("TAG","From server:"+res);// to see what server sent
if( ! res.contains("login failed")){
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(res); 
if(jArray!=null){
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject jobj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                //now, you catch the values using column_name. As,
id=jobj.getInt("_id");name= jobj.getString("Name");
//Note that here _id,Name are column names. Refer server result in logcat for better understanding
            }
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton man. I will work on this approach. But I dont understand your php code's first line. And where are we getting the sent username and password? And how can I send the username back to mobile when login is successful?

Comment: Are you familiar with phpmyadmin? first line is the link to local host. you have to provide its username&password(same as for phpmyadmin).
`$_REQUEST[]` gets the items from namevaluepair.

Comment: You are really helpful. Please tell me one more thing.

$link=mysql_connect('localhost','root','password')

If I have actual server then do I have to give it's IP address in place of 'localhost'?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know REST/java on server.

For real server, give its IP address in java(HttpPost).
 Here in php, give MySQL host name.(Eg: 'mysql.1freehosting.com'  for 1freehosting)